# Why is shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation not called in rotation 5,6?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, rotation

Everything is fine and the method "shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation" gets called for standard orientations like portrait, portrait-down, landscaperight and landscapeleft. However, I have noticed that it's not get called on orientations that is when iphone is lying on the table face down or face up. In my code [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation returns some values like 5 and 6 for that but, as I said, the rotation event method isn't called for those orientations. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> interfaceOrientation The orientation of the application’s user
>   interface after the rotation. The possible values are described in
>   UIInterfaceOrientation.

```
typedef enum {
   UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait           = UIDeviceOrientationPortrait,
   UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown = UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,
   UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft      = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight,
   UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight     = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft
} UIInterfaceOrientation;
```

As you can see the orientations are interface orientations, not device orientations.

You may want to take a look at: [Reading the accelerometer](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/iphone-tutorial-reading-the-accelerometer)

Answer (score 3):

Why would it? How should the interface orientation react if the user places the devices flat on a table? There is no way for the device to tell which orientation would be the "correct" one.

Device orientation ≠ Interface orientation